# How do I ensure that only one consumer actually consumes a published message?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, distributed-system

I use Rabbitmq with microservice architecture. I use topic and direct exchange for many of my use-cases, and it works fine. However I have a use-case where I have to delete a record from database. When I deleted the record several other services needs to be called and maintain/delete the referenced records. I could achieve that by simple call those services with direct exchange, but I read that it is choreography preferred instead orchestration. That means the I should implement publish/subscribe pattern(fanout in rabbitmq). 
My question is that if I use the publish/subscribe pattern in a distributed system how to make sure that only one instance by service consumes the published messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question doesn't deal so much with publish-subscribe, as it does with basic message processing.  The fundamental issue is whether or not you can guarantee that an operation will be performed exactly one time.  The short answer is that you probably want to use a direct exchange such that a message goes into one queue and is processed by one (of possibly many) consumers.

The long answer is that "exactly once" cannot be guaranteed, so you need to make this part of your design.

**Background**

It is best practice to have message processing be an **idempotent** operation. In fact, idempotency is a critical design assumption of almost any external interface (and I would argue it is equally-important in internal interfaces).

Additionally, you should be aware of the fact it is not possible to guarantee "exactly once" delivery. Mathematically, no such guarantee can be made. Instead, you can have one of two things (being mutually exclusive):

- At most once delivery (0 < n <= 1)
- At least once delivery (1 <= n)

From the RabbitMQ documentation:

> Use of acknowledgements guarantees at-least-once delivery. Without acknowledgements, message loss is possible during publish and consume operations and only at-most-once delivery is guaranteed.

Several things are happening when messages are published and consumed. Because of the asynchronous nature of message handling systems, and the AMQP protocol in particular, there is no way to guarantee exactly once processing while still yielding the performance you would need from a messaging system (essentially, to try to ensure exactly-once would forces everything through a serial process at the point of de-duplication).

**Design Implications**

Given the above, it is important that your design rely upon "at least once" delivery. For a delete operation, this involves re-writing the definition of that operation to be assertive rather than procedural (e.g. "Delete *this*" becomes "Ensure *this* does not exist."). The difference is that you describe the end-state rather than the process.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you should have a separate queue for each of the service that instance should be notified about db record deletion. The exchanger puts a copy of a message in all queues. Service instances compete for access to dedicated queue (only one gets a message).